# Asana Math calligraphic capital R with XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex, calligraphy

I am having problems getting a calligraphic ‘R’ with Asana Math.

This is my minimal:

```
\font\asanacal="Asana Math:script=math;mapping=script;+salt"
\font\asanascr="Asana Math:script=math;mapping=script"
\textfont2=\asanacal
\textfont6=\asanascr

$ \fam2 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ $

$ \fam6 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ $
\bye
```

[image]

I get a script R instead of calligraphic R.

This is my `script.map`:

```
LHSName "script"
RHSName "UNICODE"
pass(unicode)
U+0041 > U+1D49C
U+0042 > U+212C
U+0043 > U+1D49E
U+0044 > U+1D49F
U+0045 > U+2130
U+0046 > U+2131
U+0047 > U+1D4A2
U+0048 > U+210B
U+0049 > U+2110
U+004A > U+1D4A5
U+004B > U+1D4A6
U+004C > U+2112
U+004D > U+2133
U+004E > U+1D4A9
U+004F > U+1D4AA
U+0050 > U+1D4AB
U+0051 > U+1D4AC
U+0052 > U+211B
U+0053 > U+1D4AE
U+0054 > U+1D4AF
U+0055 > U+1D4B0
U+0056 > U+1D4B1
U+0057 > U+1D4B2
U+0058 > U+1D4B3
U+0059 > U+1D4B4
U+005A > U+1D4B5
U+0061 > U+1D4B6
U+0062 > U+1D4B7
U+0063 > U+1D4B8
U+0064 > U+1D4B9
U+0065 > U+212F
U+0066 > U+1D4BB
U+0067 > U+210A
U+0068 > U+1D4BD
U+0069 > U+1D4BE
U+006A > U+1D4BF
U+006B > U+1D4C0
U+006C > U+1D4C1
U+006D > U+1D4C2
U+006E > U+1D4C3
U+006F > U+2134
U+0070 > U+1D4C5
U+0071 > U+1D4C6
U+0072 > U+1D4C7
U+0073 > U+1D4C8
U+0074 > U+1D4C9
U+0075 > U+1D4CA
U+0076 > U+1D4CB
U+0077 > U+1D4CC
U+0078 > U+1D4CD
U+0079 > U+1D4CE
U+007A > U+1D4CF
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues here, first you need to pass `script=math` in the font definition since this features is registered with the `math` OpenType script tag, second script R is missing from Asana’s `salt` feature (bad luck `:)`), others seem to work fine.

Comment: heh, I noticed the missing "script=math" pretty much the exact same time of your answer `:-)` Bad luck indeed, as you say.